# Python RPG Inheritance Issues?

Tags: python, inheritance

I am running into a TypeError for my super().**init** method stating it only takes one positional argument and three are given. I assumed that the Enchanted class inherited the other parameters from the parent classes Weapons and Item, but I seemed to have missed something?

Using python 3.5 and link to the GitHub repository if needed is here: [PythonRPG](https://github.com/mcnuggz/PythonRPG).

```
#base item class
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name, description):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description

    def __init__(self):
        return "{}\n=====\n{}\nDamage: {}".format(self.name, self.description) 

#start weapons
class Weapons(Item):
    def __init__(self, name, description, attack):
        self.attack = attack
        super().__init__(name, description)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}\n=====\n{}\nDamage: {}".format(self.name, self.description, self.attack)

class Enchanted(Weapons):
    def __init__(self):
       #error appears here
        super().__init__(name="Enchanted Longsword", description="A prestine longsword you found with small runes inscribed along the Cross Guard. You feel a small magical force emanating from the weapon as you hold it.", attack = 12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `__init__` methods in your `Item` class. The second overwrites the first, and since it takes only one positional parameter (`self`), the error is thrown. Simple fix: get rid of the second `__init__`.

I'm not certain, but perhaps you meant your second `__init__` to be `__str__`?

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name, description):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}\n=====\n{}\nDamage: {}".format(self.name, self.description)
```

Comment: Oh wow, nice catch! Got a different error this time, so progress is made.

Answer (score 0):

A nice answer is already provided by jme. I am guessing that you are trying something like method overloading or creating different constructors for `Item` class. 
In a python class you can not have two methods of same name. But you can achieve this property by providing default values to the method parameters. Something like this:

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name=None, description=None):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
```